# glCreateProgram() is returning 0 all the time on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: opengl, shader, vertex-shader

I am new to OpenGL and shaders. I am using the sample code as given by the following link of Ohio-state university 
http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~whmin/courses/cse5542-2013-spring/13-GLSL.pdf
 But when I try running it the glCreateProgram() is always returning 0. My sample c code is given below :

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    GLuint programObject;
    programObject = glCreateProgram();

    if(programObject == 0)
    {
        printf("Error Creating shader program object.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Succeeded creating shader program object.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you never created a glcontext so all gl functions are no-ops

Comment: Would be good to post an answer with source/references